# ajax в консоле браузера вижу ответ, но в блоке SUCCES ничего не выводит

Tags: ajax, post

```
   $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: serverAddress + "api/loadFile",
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.error("папапап");
                            JSON.stringify(data);
                            console.log(data);
                            console.log("data.body");
                            console.log(data.body);
                            console.log(data.status);
                            console.error("папапап");

                        }
                    });
```

при этов в консоле браузера вкладка нетворк 200 и на сервере всё приходит, 
вкладка response выдаёт текст l2iy0be1АРМ.docx выаёт что надо но почему в консоле вообще ничего не пишется почему succes  не выполняется?

Comment: Потому что выполняется `error`.

Comment: при чем тут это? я просто хочу в консоль вывк